# $a_n$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers and $a_{n+1}\geq a_n - 2^{-n}$. Prove that $a_n $ is convergent.

My attempt: Suppose $a_n $ is not convergent then $\limsup a_n \neq \liminf a_n$. Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ converges to limsup and liminf. Then for some $x_p=a_{n_p}$ and $y_q=a_{n_q}$ we have $x_p-y_q>\epsilon$. where $n_q>n_p$. Also from given condition $x_p-y_q < \frac{1}{2^{n_p}}$. This is a contradiction for bigger $n_p$.

Is this correct?

Please help!

Comment: You haven't used the information you were given so you can't have solved the problem.

Comment: Your attempt is severely lacking and is not really an attempt, more an idea. How far did you get with the idea? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Since your sequence is bounded, if it does not converge, you may choose two subsequences which converge to different limits (clear? If not, prove it). Suppose those limits are $a>b$. Try to use your assumption to prove that $a\leq b$. That would be a contradiction. A bit nicer would be to use the fact that is every subsequence has a convergent subsequence which converges and if those limits are all equal, then the initial sequence converges to that limit. There, you can use similar arguments to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $b_n=a_n-2^{1-n}$. Then the given condition amounts to $b_{n+1}\ge b_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve your problem by looking at two cases:

**Case 1**:

From some $N$ on, the sequence $a_n$ is strictly decreasing. Convergence should be easy to prove in this case.

**Case 2**:

There is no such $N$. This means that there exists an (perhaps not strictly) increasing subsequence $a_{n_i}$ which, because it is increasing and bounded, has a limit $L$.

For any other $n$, to show that the value $a_n$ is close to $L$, first find the largest $n_i$ such that $n>n_i$, then use the fact that

$$\begin{align}a_n \geq a_{n-1}-2^{-(n-1)} &\geq a_{n-2}-2^{-(n-2)}-2^{-(n-1)}\\&\geq\cdots\geq a_{n_i} - \left(2^{-n_i}+2^{-n_i - 1} + \cdots + 2^{-n+1}\right)\\&\geq a_{n-i} + 2^{-n_i}\left(1 + \frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots\right)\end{align}$$